# Is rebooting my computer about 6X/hr for 6 hrs harmful?

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Is rebooting my computer about 6X/hr for 6 hrs everyday harmful? I am using the restart option through the start menu. The purpose of my rebooting is that I am installing and uninstalling different software on my windows 7 computer.

Comment: You should use [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=does+frequent+reboot+harm+pc#channel=cs&q=does+frequent+rebooting+harm+computer) or do a simple search on the website before asking questions. You can look for more info on the subject [here](http://superuser.com/questions/284770/are-frequent-reboots-in-a-short-period-of-time-damaging-my-computer) and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/258064/should-servers-be-turned-off-at-night).

Comment: 6 times an hour for 6 hours everyday?  Installing software?  Im curious what excatly are you doing and why?  There may be a better solution to your needs if we knew what you were trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

No, it's completely harmless. You can reboot your computer as often as you want so long as you're not yanking out the power cord or something like that.